# Clean debug output function?

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor

I want to write an function that will print out error messages/warnings in my program together with the file & line number. There are these two macros in **C**:

```
__FILE__
__LINE__
```

but there's a problem in my opinion... When I'm writing a function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define AT __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)
void error(const char *location, const char *msg)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("Error at %s: %s\n", location, msg);
#endif
}
int main(int , char**)
{
  error(AT, "fake error");
  return 0;
}
```

There are still a lot of useless function calls & trash (the values of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` at every call) in the binary file, even if I undefine `DEBUG` for the release build.
So how can I accomplish this more elegant? I want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define AT __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)
void error(const char *location, const char *msg)
{
  printf("Error at %s: %s\n", location, msg);
}
int main(int , char**)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  error(AT, "fake error");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

But not writing `#ifdef DEBUG` and `#endif` before and after every function call - that would be too huge for such an task. And remove every  `error(AT, "fake error");` call manually isn't really elegant as well...

Any ideas? Maybe inline the function (would not help, wouldn't it)? Some macro or an change of this construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping `error()` in a macro is indeed the right way to go - I'd write it like so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static void error(const char *file, long line, const char *msg)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error (%s:%ld): %s\n", file, line, msg);
}
#define error(msg) (error)(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#else
#define error(msg) ((void)0)
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Just turn `error` into a macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define ERROR(l, m) error(l, m)
#else
# define ERROR(l, m)
#endif
```

then, in your functions, write

```
ERROR(AT, "fake error");
```

Of course, you could also simplify ERROR and get rid of `AT` as the first parameter, directly specifying this information in the macro definition.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this variadic macro to mimic `printf` which writes file and line no with desired out put.

```
#define eprintf(...) do {fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
 fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);} while(0)
```

edit : modified eprintf from the suggestions of jcsalomon

Comment: This is for C99 or C++0x only, and would be better defined `#define eprintf(...) do {fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)} while(0)`; note the statements wrapped in a `do{…}while(0)`, and (more to the point) `fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)` which lets you pass a raw string without extra argument.

Comment: ya i know, tats why i wrote it will be similar to above statement.

Comment: Just tried it and there's a missing `;` after `__VA_ARGS__)` otherwise it's a really nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ERROR(msg) error(AT, msg)
#else
#define ERROR(msg)
#endif

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   ERROR( "fake error");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace error with #define

something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define error(a,b) printf("Error at %s: %s\n", (a), (b))
#else
#define error(a,b) 
#endif
```

You could also move AT into error instead of passing it each time